# Sictus Program is not open

Tags: sicstus-prolog

I couldn't start my Sictus program. It shows an error like

```
"The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is 
missing from your computer."
```

I successfully install Visual Studio 2012 as well.But it did not runtut. Please help me to run this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not happen if SICStus was installed with the installer on your machine. If it does, it looks like a bug in the installer, please contact SICStus support.

If this is an earlier version than Windows 10, it may help to install https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/.